# Why are pointers of structs not printed like pointers of variables?

Tags: language-design, pointers, go

Consider the following code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y int
}

var (
    i = 10
    p = &i
    v = Vertex{1,2}
    q = &v
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(p) // Outputs the memory location of the pointer
    fmt.Println(q) // Outputs the string &{1 2}
}
```

Why isn't the memory location of pointer `q` printed, like it is with `p`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because go allows you to use type pointers the same way you would use a regular var. So if you pass a pointer to a type the receiving function will operate on the original copy. If you pass a copy of the data than the modifications do not get applied back to the original var.

If the function explicitly asks for a pointer than you have to pass a pointer.

Here is a modification of your example that might clarify how go works.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y int
}

var (
    i = 10
    p = &i
    v = Vertex{1, 2}
    q = &v
    t = &v.X
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(p) // Outputs the memory location of the pointer
    fmt.Println(q) // Outputs the string &{1 2}
    fmt.Println(t)
    fmt.Println(&q)
}
```

This section from [Effective GO](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values)

> **Pointers vs. Values**
>
> ```
> As we saw with ByteSize, methods can be defined for any named type (except
> a pointer or an interface); the receiver does not have to be a
> struct.
>
> In the discussion of slices above, we wrote an Append function. We can
> define it as a method on slices instead. To do this, we first
> declare a named type to which we can bind the method, and then make
> the receiver for the method a value of that type.
>
>     type ByteSlice []byte
>
>     func (slice ByteSlice) Append(data []byte) []byte {
>     // Body exactly the same as the Append function defined above.
>     }
> This still requires the method to return the updated slice. We can
> eliminate that clumsiness by redefining the method to take a pointer
> to a ByteSlice as its receiver, so the method can overwrite the
> caller's slice.
>
>     func (p *ByteSlice) Append(data []byte) {
>         slice := *p
>         // Body as above, without the return.
>         *p = slice
>     }
> In fact, we can do even better. If we modify our function so it looks like
> a standard Write method, like this,
>
>     func (p *ByteSlice) Write(data []byte) (n int, err error) {
>         slice := *p
>         // Again as above.
>         *p = slice
>         return len(data), nil
>     }
> then the type *ByteSlice satisfies the standard interface io.Writer, which
> is handy. For instance, we can print into one.
>
>     var b ByteSlice
>     fmt.Fprintf(&b, "This hour has %d days\n", 7)
> We pass the address of a ByteSlice because only *ByteSlice satisfies
> io.Writer. The rule about pointers vs. values for receivers
> is that value methods can be invoked on pointers and values, but
> pointer methods can only be invoked on pointers.
>
> This rule arises because pointer methods can modify the receiver; invoking
> them on a value would cause the method to receive a copy of
> the value, so any modifications would be discarded. The language
> therefore disallows this mistake. There is a handy exception, though.
> When the value is addressable, the language takes care of the common
> case of invoking a pointer method on a value by inserting the address
> operator automatically. In our example, the variable b is addressable,
> so we can call its Write method with just b.Write. The compiler will
> rewrite that to (&b).Write for us.
>
> By the way, the idea of using Write on a slice of bytes is central to the
> implementation of bytes.Buffer.
> ```